# ActiveRecord errors, how do I find out the locale path to change the messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I know you can change ActiveRecord error messages in the locales like this:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              blank: "is required"
```

But that is an incredibly specific tree—how do I know what ActiveRecord is looking for? Is there a way to inspect an error to see what path ActiveRecord is searching? Or is there a way to generate a complete `en.yml` with all messages in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ActiveModel::Error` class (what you get if you call `record.errors`) has a `details` attribute, which is a hash of the attributes and their errors, including the error key.

```rb
foo.valid?
=> false
foo.errors.details
=> {:user=>[{:error=>:blank}]}
```

The [ActiveModel source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/locale/en.yml) has an `en.yml`, which will give you the canonical set of keys. The `rails-i18n` gem includes translations for many of the standard keys, but there are definite gaps (that is, some locales are complete, some are not).

As @Mirror318 says, you can see the set of error message translations for the current locale by running `I18n.t 'errors'`. If your current locale is `en.yml` that will be the same as the canonical list; otherwise it is the available set of translated messages.

Answer (score 1):

In a Rails console, you can enter:

```
I18n.t 'errors'
```

And that will return a hash of all current error messages. You can adjust that hash via the locale `.yml` file